# Proving function has a specific value in its domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

If $a$ and $b$ $\in \Bbb{R}$, $a \neq b$, and $f(x)=(x-a)^2 (x-b)^2 + x$. Show that $f$ gets the value $\frac{a+b}{2}$ at some $x$ in its domain.

I'm trying to prove this by the intermediate-value theorem. Since $f$ is continuous in its domain, we can say that $f(x) = \frac{a+b}{2}$ exists if $$f(x_1)\leq f(x)=\frac{a+b}{2}\leq f(x_2)$$

is true for some $x_1 , x_2$ in the domain of $f$. One way to show this, is to differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$ and find $f_{min}$ and/or $f_{max}$, but since $f'$ is quite convoluted I don't think its necessarily the best idea. We can plug in $0$ and show that $f(0)=a^2 b^2 > f(x)$, i.e $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is not the largest value of $f$. Other than that I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Use that $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a<b$

Then $f(a)=a<b=f(b)$

Now you can use the intermediate value theorem since $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

Answer (score 2):

$f(a)=a, f(b)=b$ apply the intermediate value theorem